# Generation of n_th anonymouse Walsh function

Tags: function, matlab, math

I need Walsh functions for fourier approximation of some test function (let it be sinx on interval from -pi to pi). So I need to find n_th Walsh function as a function of x to use in integral for coefficients.

Here is my try (I tried to use haddamar matrices)

```
function y = wal(x,n)
N = 2^n;
H = hadamard(N); 
id = fix(x*N -1e-9) + 1;
y = H(N,id);
```

end

But here is my problem, first of all these functions are not correct. Secondly, they are defined only on (0,1) interval, and I don't know how to generalise in on [-pi,pi]. Thirdly input x is an array, and I need to make anonymous func @(x), but then my id is undefined and function is not working at all.
In addition I add some mathematical background on Walsh functions. They are specific case of orthonormal basis defined on interval [0,1]. It can be constructed from Rademachers system in the following way:

[image: eq 1]

[image: eq 2]

Where nk is a value of k-th digit of Gray biniary representation of number n. Rule of Gray representation:

[image: eq 3]

For example for n=4 binary is 100 and Gray representation nk = 110 and thus we obtain formula for walsh function is this case:

[image: eq 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in your domain, but from the description it seems not easy to devise `walsh` with one anonymous function **only**.

Below is one possible implementation of the `walsh.m` function, where the last two are helper functions

```
% walsh function
function y = walsh(x, n)
nk = grayencoding(n);
y = prod(rademachers(x, length(nk):-1:1).^nk);
end

% rademachers system
function y = rademachers(x, n)
if n == 0
    y = 1;
else
    y = sign(sin(2.^n.*pi.*x));
end
end

% gray binary encoding
function y = grayencoding(k)
v = dec2binvec(k);
y = zeros(size(v));
for p = 1:(length(v)-1) 
    y(p) = xor(v(p),v(p+1));
end
y(end) = v(end);
y = fliplr(y);
end
```